# What serial file transfer protocol to use?

Tags: ftp, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm looking for some input on witch file transfer protocol to use over a serial line. I want to be able to transfer files of max 200 Mb size over a serial line (RS232) in both directions, but only one of the machines needs to be able to initiate the get/put (think master-slave).

The protocol also needs to be:

- Easy/simple to implement since I would need to write both client and server myself (limited, embedded hardware)
- Fairly robust, fault checking/recovery etc
- At least somewhat standardized, in case I need to get a third party to implement it on some other hardware

Kermit? TFTP? Simplest possible home brew? What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the beginning was the [Xmodem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM), which was very simple to implement. Chuck Forsberg looked at the xmodem and decided it was inefficient, so he begat the [Ymodem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YMODEM), but it's implementations were buggy and both x and ymodem were replaced with [Zmodem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM).

[Kermit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermit_%28protocol%29) followed on later. Kermit would probably be the "Standard" way to implement this. Do you have access to libraries for Kermit that will run on your embedded platform? If not I would probably consider one of the other options.

If ease of implementation is your primary concern then Xmodem wins hands down.